# Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'module'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am new to angular2, i want to put multiple component in one routing.module.ts and multiple module in one module.ts.But i got an error `Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'JobfileModule'.` I have searh for any possible solution but i still cannot solve it and still confused with my style of code.

this is my code

`routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { JobComponent } from './job.component';
import { JobfileComponent } from './jobfile.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: JobComponent, data: {
      title: 'Job' }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: JobfileComponent, data: {
      title: 'JobFile' }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]

})
export class JobRoutingModule {}
```

and `my module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
import { JobComponent } from './job.component';
import { JobfileComponent } from './jobfile.component';
import { JobRoutingModule } from './job-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    JobRoutingModule,
    ChartsModule
  ],
  declarations: [ JobComponent, JobfileComponent  ]
})
export class JobModule { }
export class JobfileModule { }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

you need to decleare your component at your JobRoutingModule and not your app module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [ JobComponent, JobfileComponent  ]
})
export class JobRoutingModule {}
```

and remove export class JobModule { } you not use it

Comment: i got another error

 'Type JobComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: JobRoutingModule and JobModule! Please consider moving JobComponent to a higher module that imports JobRoutingModule and JobModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes JobComponent then import that NgModule in JobRoutingModule and JobModule.'

Comment: remove declarations: [ JobComponent, JobfileComponent  ] from module.ts

Comment: already remove... but i got another error 'Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'job' '

this is how i declare my routes


{ path: '',redirectTo: 'job',pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '',component: FullLayoutComponent,data: {title: 'Job Assignment' },
    children: [ {path: 'job',loadChildren: './job/job.module#JobModule' }, ]
  },